# Not able to upload build using Fabric/Crashlytics

Tags: ios, xcode, crashlytics, twitter-fabric

This morning I installed the latest Crashlytics plugin (Fabric was showing the '!') as well as Xcode 7.0.1

Now I am no longer able to upload a beta build. Usually after an archive action finishes I'd see the 'Distribute' button. Now nothing. Can anyone help me out here?

The Fabric plugin also no longer seems to live in the menu bar. Not sure if that's related.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mike from Crashlytics and Fabric here.

If you quit and relaunch Fabric.app that will pull in the latest version of Fabric.app which has a fix for this. The version would be 2.0.1.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Restarting the Fabric app does not seem to update the app though. I currently have version 2.0.0

Comment: Gotcha, try leaving Fabric.app open for about 5 minutes, then quit and relaunch the app.

Comment: @MikeB I am on Fabric 2.0.2 and trying to distribute the build from XCode 6.4 (old project) but the app kinda starts to upload and quickly switches to the empty screen showing just the app name and the build is not available.

What am I missing?

Comment: @MilosZikic Hmm, it's not quite clear, but try this out. Quit Fabric.app and then run this command to clear the local cache:

rm -rf ~/Library/Caches/com.crashlytics.mac

Then restart Fabric.app and let me know how it goes.

Comment: Tried it and it did not work. What I did at the end is to remove the app from Fabric and initialise a new one, which then gave me the instructions to use the new shell script and then it worked.

Comment: Very odd, but glad to hear you're all set!

Comment: we're having similar problems. we can't install any Beta builds anymore. Tried clearing the cache, downloading new Fabric, etc. Even deleted a "dev" organization we had copies of. Is there a guide on how to completely uninstall Fabric/Crashlytics and reinstall fresh? We don;t have the freedom to delete our Live Production app to start over. Thanks!

Comment: That sounds like a different issue then what the parent posted. I'd advise creating a separate question.

Answer (score 31):

if your the upload doesn't start automatically when you archive you can still do it manually.
On the Fabric app, select the Beta tab. Then first click "ACTIVE", then click "ARCHIVES": now you'll see the IPA you archived.

Comment: Yer a wizard lucianoenrico

Comment: After clicking Archives, you may need to wait short while before the UI updates (presumably while Fabric scans the relevant folders). Previously I'd clicked this, nothing had happened and clicked away thinking it wasn't working.

Comment: OMG i've always wished Fabric would support this for when the connection to xcode breaks (i can't get it to prompt me to distribute anymore).  thank you!

Comment: How comes that something widely used as fabric has such in unintuitive interface?